# ¿Cómo ejecutar función JavaScript desde input type="image"?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Necesito ejecutar una función JavaScript al hacer click en una imagen, en mi HTML  agregue este código:

```
  <input type="image" src="../Content/imagen/Der.JPG" class="btn btn-success" onclick="Navegacion('GameATwo.aspx');"/>
```

y en mi script tengo esto, pero no está funcionando, ¿Qué estoy haciendo mal?

```
function Navegacion(page) {
    window.open(page, '_self');
}
```

Comment: Que es lo que no funciona exactamante? Algun error? O es que no abre la pestaña directamente? Ami me funciona tu ejemplo.

Comment: No esta abriendo la pagina que nesecito en la misma pestaña... onclick="Navegacion('GameATwo.aspx');"  si lo hago con un boton funciona bien

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solucione usando un boton al cual le puse como background una imagen.

Html

```
<input id="image" type="button" class="btn btn-success arrowLeft" onClick="Navegacion('GameATwo.aspx');"/>
```

Css

```
.arrowLeft {
    cursor: pointer;
    border: none;
    width: 47px;
    height: auto;
    background: url('/Content/imagen/Der.JPG') no-repeat;
    padding:0%
}
```

JavaScript

```
function Navegacion(page) {
    window.open(page, "_self");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Estimado, prueba este código, es otra forma de acceso para lo que necesitas y una opción a implementar que evita que todo lo creado dinamicamente tenga ese problema de acceso (dado que existe la posibilidad de que este objeto no se cree en el DOM).

```js
$(document).on('click', '#miImagen', function() {
  var page = $('#miImagen').attr('name');
  window.open(page, '_self');
  return false;
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="miImagen" type="image" src="../Content/imagen/Der.JPG" class="btn btn-success" name="GameATwo.aspx" />
```

Saludos, cualquier cosa me comentas.

**EDIT**

Añado este sector como nuevo intento de apertura. Verifica también que la página esté en la misma altura para ser llamada.

```js
$(document).on('click', '#miImagen', function() {
  var page = $('#miImagen').attr('name');
  window.location.href = page;
  return false;
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="miImagen" type="image" src="../Content/imagen/Der.JPG" class="btn btn-success" name="GameATwo.aspx" />
```

**EDIT 2**

Estimado, añadí un `return false` en ambos códigos. Esto es para que el formulario no se quede esperando una respuesta del servidor y vaya directamente a la página.

Comment: Hola harifo... No funciona ...agregue un console.log('hola mundo'); y lo imprime en la consola pero no carga la nueva pagina dentro de la misma pestaña...es muy raro

Comment: Estimado, actualizaré mi respuesta para que pruebes otra forma.

Comment: Nada estimado, el navegador hace la accion como de redireccionar perono renderiza la pagina deseada y siii ambas paginas estan dentro de la misma carpeta

Comment: Tengo otro intento, resulta que existen agunos navegadores que tienen problemas con este código en particular, reemplaza window.location.href por esta linea: `window.location.replace(page);` y me comentas.

Comment: Harifo..Gracias pero todo en vano..